# kdb: inter-process bulk insert

Tags: kdb

I have an easy question regarding inter-process bulk insert but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Let there be a process `p1` on port `localhost:5001`, and a process `p2`

`p1` contains the following table:

```
TEST:([] name:(); salary:());
```

From `p2` I would like to do the following:

```
DATA:([] name:`John`Foe;salary:1 2);

h:hopen `::5001;
h "insert[`TEST](",string[DATA],")"
```

Now the last syntax is obviously wrong (gives `'length` error), so what should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
         q)h (insert; `TEST;DATA)
```

Syntax for calling function on a service from other service using handle:

```
          h(function;func_parameters)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there must be some sort of specific handle syntax :)